# Symfony - post elements of an array to db

Tags: php, arrays, database, symfony

I got this file.. [My list of arrays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJhse.jpg)

I need to populate to fields in db(type and data field). One field (data) where I return all array objects as string, that I did. And another (type) where I need to return Card Authorisation, Card Financial etc,.

This is my db.

[My database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlOEu.jpg)

My function is populating the data field like it should but I dont know how to populate type field that I mentioned.

This is my code..

```
public function serializeTransactions()
{
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("/var/www/html/web/uploads/gps-trans.xml");

    $response = json_decode(json_encode((array)$xml), true);

    foreach ($xml as $result) {
        $result = (array)$result;
        $gps = new Transactions();
        $gps->setType();
        $gps->setData(json_encode($result));

        $this->em->persist($gps);
    };

    $this->em->flush();
}
```

Sorry if my English is not that good, I could really use some help.

Comment: I'm sorry but what is your question? Is your code not working and how so?

Comment: $gps->setType();   I need to populate that field with Card Authorisation, Card Financial etc,. (see image).. Other field is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is weird ...

```
$response = json_decode(json_encode((array)$xml), true);
```

is what for?

However ... if you want to save the type with `$gps->setType();` and assuming, your $result is type of SimpleXMLElement ... what about

```
foreach ($xml as $result) {
    $gps = new Transactions();
    $gps->setType($result->getName());
    $gps->setData(json_encode((array)$result));

    $this->em->persist($gps);
};
```

???

Comment: Call to a member function getName() on array is an error. If I try $result->getName($xml) it return the name of the whole xml file and the ones I need are Card Authorisation, Card Financial etc..

Comment: Edited my answer ... just remove the type cast from SimplexXmlElement to array and add it later if needed ... if your are not in the right deep, just go deeper in xml tree ... i dont know your initial xml

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for replay. I found the solution.

```
 public function serializeTransactions()
{
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("/var/www/html/web/uploads/gps-trans.xml");

    foreach ($xml as $key => $result) {

        $result = (array)$result;
        $gps = new Transactions();
        $gps->setType($key);
        $gps->setData(json_encode($result));

        $this->em->persist($gps);
    };

    $this->em->flush();
}
```